# Need help formulating a Traveling Salesman (Deliveryman) Variation

Tags: graph-theory, linear-programming

I am working with the following TSP variation:

A deliveryman has to deliver orders of items to several different locations around a city. The orders are:

```
Store 1: 25 items
Store 2: 60 items
Store 3: 20 items
Store 5: 10 items
Store 6: 20 items
Store 7: 50 items
Store 8: 70 items
Store 9: 15 items
```

And one constraint is that the truck can only carry 90 items at once, so he needs to optimize for both distance and load/capacity.

Can someone help me to describe this mathematically? Perhaps point me toward an algorithm or a formula?

Comment: So how can it be considered? If you do not know the coordinates of the shops.

Comment: I don't think the coordinates of the shops are important here; I am just looking for help with which formula or algorithm to use!

Comment: How does this sound for a start, i.e., step 1 of an algorithm: eliminate all combinations of deliveries whose items sums are greater than 90. Then I would have a smaller set of possible deliveries. Then I can compare each of those on the basis of optimal distance. I still don't know how to formulate this, though.

Comment: To rephrase my above comment, I limit possible tours to those whose sums of items are less than or equal to 90. Then I do some sort of calculation on the set of tours remaining to come up with the optimal set, and lowest number, of tours.

Comment: It is necessary to know the coordinates of the store. Bust looking for solutions.  This modified task of the Pitcher. http://www.mathforum.ru/forum/read/1/71187/71187/#71187

Comment: I cannot read Russian---do you have English? Also, I am not looking for a solution here, but help with identifying the approach to use at all: recommendations on what approaches/formulas/algorithms to use.

Comment: The only algorithm is to iterate over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have figured out what type of problem this is, and identified a source of solutions: I think this is a "Capacitated Vehicle Routing Problem," and [this link from Uni Heidelberg](http://www.iwr.uni-heidelberg.de/groups/comopt/software/TSPLIB95/) appears to have some solutions.